# AudioKit Audio Player - Plays each track out of sync

Tags: swiftui, audiokit

I'm developing an app to practice mixing with 16 different tracks. I load each file within a function and play them all by pressing one button, but they start playing at different times, resulting in the audio being out of sync. Do you know how to make sure everything is synced? When the files are played in a DAW they are all perfectly in sync so that's not the problem, it's something within the code.

**Main App File**

```
import swiftUI
import UIKit

@main
struct MixLabApp: App {
    @StateObject var conductor = MixerClass()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FreePlayMain()
                .environmentObject(conductor)
        }
    }
}
```

**Mixer Class** (Slimlined to make easier to understand)

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit
import AVFoundation

final class MixerClass: ObservableObject {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var mixer = Mixer()
    
    @Published var track1 = AudioPlayer()
    @Published var track2 = AudioPlayer()
    @Published var track3 = AudioPlayer()

    @Published var isTrack1Playing: Bool = false
    @Published var isTrack2Playing: Bool = false
    @Published var isTrack3Playing: Bool = false

    init() {
        do {
            Settings.bufferLength = .medium
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredIOBufferDuration((Settings.bufferLength.duration))
            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

        do {
            if let track1FileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DQ_Kick", withExtension: "mp3") {
                try track1.load(url: track1FileURL)
            } else {
                Log("Could not find Track 1 file")
            }
            
            if let track2FileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DQ_Snare", withExtension: "mp3") {
                try track2.load(url: track2FileURL)
            } else {
                Log("Could not find Track 2 file")
            }
            
            if let track3FileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DQ_Tom1", withExtension: "mp3") {
                try track3.load(url: track3FileURL)
            } else {
                Log("Could not find Track 3 file")
            }

        track1.isLooping = true
        track2.isLooping = true
        track3.isLooping = true
    }

 func playStopToggle() {
        
        isTrack1Playing ? track1.stop() : track1.start()
        isTrack1Playing.toggle()
        
        isTrack2Playing ? track2.stop() : track2.start()
        isTrack2Playing.toggle()
        
        isTrack3Playing ? track3.stop() : track3.start()
        isTrack3Playing.toggle()
    }
}
```

**FreePlayMain**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FreePlayMain: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var conductor: MixerClass
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Slider(value: $conductor.track1.volume, in: 0...1)
                        .padding()
                    Slider(value: $conductor.track2.volume, in: 0...1)
                        .padding()
                    Slider(value: $conductor.track3.volume, in: 0...1)
                        .padding()
                }
                playStopButton
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var playStopButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            conductor.playStopToggle()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Text("\(Image(systemName: conductor.isTrack1Playing ? "stop.fill" : "play.fill")) \(conductor.isTrack1Playing ? "Stop" : "Start") Track 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already found a solution to this, but i had a similar issue a few months ago and the trick was to use the .play(at:) method to provide a unified start time to all tracks. Here's what that line looks like in mine playbackChannels is an array of objects that each contain an audioKit player

```
self.playbackChannels.forEach{
        $0.getAudioPlayer().play(from: 0, at: startTime)
}
```